# Applet within div tag issue

Tags: html, css

I have to paste some applet code within a div tag whose min-height is set to a fixed number and height to auto . However in the applet definition if i set the applet height to 100% it only fits as high as the min-height the rest is hidden .

Also the div does not increase its height .

My HTML is as follows

```
<div class="someclass" >

<applet width="100%" height="100%" name="" code="">

       <!-- some content-->

        <blockquote>
            Your browser is not Java-enabled, please download the latest Java runtime from <a href="http://www.java.com">http://www.java.com</a>
        </blockquote>        


    </applet>

</div>
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: does the applet have a fixed height? you could just apply that height to the applet?

Comment: Your div has to have a fixed height if you want 100% height from the applet to work.

Comment: No the applet content height varies for different applets .and i cannot have a fixed height i need the height to scale according to the applet height .Is that possible?'

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment regarding the Java applet, but it seems like you could use the DOM and Javascript to detect the height dynamically, and then resize the window. It would depend on how the applet is initialized within the browser. To give more specific help, I think we could use a bit more background on the project.